# IIS Site inside another site, different web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an MVC web app on my iis with windows authentication. I have a folder called Content which holds all of my images.

I want that the Content folder will be freely excessed so I converted the Content folder to an application. The problem is that my main web.config is being read and it looks for WebGrease in Content/bin which it obviously cant find.

Is there a way to make the Content web app use a different web.config?

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded by wrapping some of my web config sections in my parent's web.config with the location tag

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7(v=vs.100).aspx